# How to create a cURL POST request in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to figure out how to create a PHP cURL POST request. I have the following code to use. I'm a bit stuck on what the -g -X and -H means.

```
curl -g -X POST -H 'Authorization: bearer <access_token>' -d 'superTasks=["IEAE34A4KQATKP4S"]&metadata=[{"key":"testMetaKey","value":"testMetaValue"}]&priorityBefore=IEAE34A4KQATKP4S&importance=High&customFields=[{"id":"IEAE34A4JUAADKT3","value":"testValue"}]&description=Test task description&dates={"start":"2016-05-18","due":"2016-05-25"}&title=Test task&follow=true&followers=["KUAHYFH4"]&responsibles=["KUAHYFH4"]&shareds=["KUAHYFH4"]&parents=["IEAE34A4I4ATKP4L"]&status=Active' 'https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/folders/IEAE34A4I4ATKP4L/tasks'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT Added code below:

```
$postData = array(
    "title" => "Test task",
    "description" => "Test task description",
    "status" => "Active",
    "importance" => "Normal",
    "dates" => {"start":"2016-05-18","due":"2016-05-25"},
    "shareds" => ["KUAHYFH4"],
    "parents" => ["IEAE34A4I4ATKP4L"],
    "responsibles" => ["KUAHYFH4"],
    "followers" => ["KUAHYFH4"],
    "follow" => "true",
    "priorityBefore" => "IEAE34A4KQATKP4S",
    "priorityAfter" => "IEAE34A4KQATKP4S",
    "superTasks" => "["IEAE34A4KQATKP4S"]",
    "metadata" => "[{"key":"testMetaKey","value":"testMetaValue"}]"),
    "customFields" => [{"id":"IEAE34A4JUAADKT3","value":"testValue"}],
    "customStatus" => "string"
    );

$handler = curl_init();

curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/folders/IEAE34A4I4ATKP4L/tasks");
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_exec($handler);
```

By doing curl -h I got the following information:

-g, --globoff       Disable URL sequences and ranges using {} and []

-X, --request COMMAND  Specify request command to use

-H, --header LINE   Pass custom header LINE to server (H)

-d, --data DATA     HTTP POST data (H)

But I can't figure out how to add these attributes.

Comment: Where is your PHP code? PHP has cURL support built in, no need for calling on the command line.

Comment: do a `curl -h` and it will explain the flags being used.

Comment: how about read the manual? https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 4):

The Problem could be in the way you have formatted the values in the `$postData` array.
All values including the JSON text should be in single quotes.
Look at how I did it though the response was an error which I believe is a valid error

```
$postData = array(
    "title" => "Test task",
    "description" => "Test task description",
    "status" => "Active",
    "importance" => "Normal",
    "dates" => '{"start":"2016-05-18","due":"2016-05-25"}',
    "shareds" => '["KUAHYFH4"]',
    "parents" => '["IEAE34A4I4ATKP4L"]',
    "responsibles" => '["KUAHYFH4"]',
    "followers" => '["KUAHYFH4"]',
    "follow" => "true",
    "priorityBefore" => "IEAE34A4KQATKP4S",
    "priorityAfter" => "IEAE34A4KQATKP4S",
    "superTasks" => '["IEAE34A4KQATKP4S"]',
    "metadata" => '[{"key":"testMetaKey","value":"testMetaValue"}]',
    "customFields" => '[{"id":"IEAE34A4JUAADKT3","value":"testValue"}]',
    "customStatus" => "string"
    );

$handler = curl_init();
$access_token = "<access_token>";
$headers[] = 'Authorization: bearer '.$access_token;


curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/folders/IEAE34A4I4ATKP4L/tasks");
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($handler);

if($response !==false)
{
  var_dump($response);
}
else {
  print "Could not get a response";
}
```

The response was

```
{"errorDescription":"Access token is unknown or invalid","error":"not_authorized"}
```

Answer (score -5):

Curl -h should help you discover what each -option means. As others advised, you could read the curl manual to see all the curl options/functions

Comment: this isn't an answer